# Display css and javascript code as it does when files are saved in their format. But inside html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use notepad++ and have got an index.html file that contains css and javascript.

Is there a way to display css and javascript code as it does when files are saved in their format; but in this case inside the html file?

Any editor, software, plugin for notepad++?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you are asking for a multi-language coloring add-in, I don't know of one for notepad++. You might try brackets or atom to see if they colorize the various languages within an HTML file.

Comment: @argoc 

Exactly!

In this case, one for HTML, PHP,  CSS, JavaScript.

Will check brackets and atom.
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript libraries [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) or [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com/) to highlight the `<pre>` and `<code>`. Another way is to embed the code with [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Download the javascript library or use the following for Highlight.js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Usage:`<pre><code class="css"> --you code goes here-- </code></pre>`, change the class name to  `class="js"` for javascript.

For Prism.js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/themes/prism.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.8.4/prism.min.js"></script>
```

Usage:`<pre><code class="language-css"> --you code goes here-- </code></pre>`, change the class name to  `class="language-js"` for javascript.

Various themes are available for each library.

---

To embed you code using [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/), paste your code and create public gist. Then copy the embed link provided and paste it on your html.

Comment: Hi @NuelG

Will go through the options you listed and report back!
Very useful info.
Cheers! :)

Comment: @itrelated Thank you! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*I did not fully understand what you are asking but here is my answer:
To add a javascript file/library to your HTML:
    
To add javascript directly into your HTML code: 
    Some script here...<\script>
To add a CSS file to your HTML:
    
To add CSS directly into your HTML code:
     Your CSS...*

**EDIT**

So now I understand what you want but I don't know of any add ons. Personally when i started coding HTML and the other related languages I used Coffee Cup free HTML editor: https://www.coffeecup.com/
Now I code for more professional uses and i downloaded a very large editor called Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: As @argoc said. I look for a multi-language coloring add-in.

In this case, one for HTML, PHP, CSS, JavaScript.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks!
Have tried Microsoft Visual Studio before.

But i am getting good results with Notepad++, plugins and the browser only.

Maybe upgrading to Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is a good idea. 
I'l try!